# Outlook sets wrong "Date" header

Tags: exchange, outlook

When sending new emails, the date header is not set in UTC +0100. Problem occurs on every client (WTSx5) and with different Users.

The dateheader:

**Date: Wed, 1 Oct 2014 09:10:05 +0000**

To the environment: The PDC is an Windows SBS 2011 Standard SP1 running Exchange 2010 SP3 UR7. 
The clients are virtualized (esx) WTS (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1) with Outlook 2010 SP3.
The active directory/exchange was migrated from a Windows Server 2003 long time ago.

Here's the complete mailheader:

```
 Received: from XXXXXX (XXXXXX) by XXXXXX (XXXXXX)
 with Microsoft SMTP Server id 8.3.348.2; Wed, 1 Oct 2014 11:10:07 +0200
Received: from XXXXXXX (XXXXXX [XXXXXX])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher AES128-SHA (128/128 bits))    (No client certificate
 requested)    by XXXXXX (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 1AB3661B0    for
 <XXXXXX>; Wed,  1 Oct 2014 11:10:07 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from XXXXXX ([XXXXXX]) by
 XXXXXX ([XXXXXX]) with mapi id
 14.03.0123.003; Wed, 1 Oct 2014 11:10:06 +0200
From: XXXXXX <XXXXXX>
To: "'XXXXXX'" <XXXXXX>
Subject: test
Thread-Topic: test
Thread-Index: Ac/dV31MtwlztB1TQ3yk+9CQOdpbNA==
Date: Wed, 1 Oct 2014 09:10:05 +0000
Message-ID: <B28CD7D4F2AD8843A3DDA35C565652FC2654C3@SBS.kanzlei.local>
Accept-Language: de-DE, en-US
Content-Language: de-DE
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-originating-ip: [XXXXXX]
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    boundary="_004_B28CD7D4F2AD8843A3DDA35C565652FC2654C3SBSkanzleilocal_";
    type="multipart/alternative"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Return-Path: XXXXXX
```

I've tested this behavior in another similar environment (same outlook and exchange version) and there, the dateheader is set to UTC +0200 (Timezone is UTC +0100 with Daylight savings)

I've checked the date/time-settings on every machine mentioned above. The date/time-settings are ok.

I'm not sure where outlook gets the time for the dateheader from. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** After some further research i found out that this is normal behavior of exchange 2010. I tested it in some other environments with exchange 2010 servers and the dateheader is set in UTC.

I'am not sure why the dateheader is set correctly in my first testing environment (doubble checked that it's an exchange 2010 server). Maybe some Header rewriting?

Comment: This seems to be an Exchange issue (I have one in my environment with same simptoms as yours, though this should not be an issue and nobody ever complained). Is the date/time/zone/savings on Exchange server set correctly?

Comment: @dusan.bajic I've again checked the date/time/zone/savings on the exchange. It's correctly set to UTC +0100 with daylightsavings on

Comment: Same here. How did you even notice this, it should not cause any problem?

Comment: @dusan One of our customer noticed it and it is a problem when they communicate with their customers, especially those who don't use Outlook as a mailclient. In their inbox the wrong time is displayed and they are complaining about it. That's why i need a solution for this specific problem.

Comment: Hm, this seems to be by (Exchange) design for all mail leaving the domain. Have you tested your similar environment for mail sent to external recipients?

Comment: @dusan Thanks for the hint, i first tested it just internally. When i mail to an external recipient from the similar environment the dateheader is correct (UTC +0200).